# How did this note "19/65 21/90 22/130" help previous owner of this old Zenit 12XP film camera?

Tags: exposure, aperture, old-cameras, film-cameras, zenit

## Camera info

The camera in question is an old **Zenit 12XP**. It belonged to my passed-away father-in-law.

It has shutter speed regulations: B, 30-X, 60, 125, 250, 500

"ГОСТ/ASA" (ISO): 16 * 32 * 65 * 130 * 250 * 500

And **HELIOS-44M-4 2/58** lens (aperture 2-16).

## Note

He stuck a note on the back of the camera body - I guess it could be something similar to [sunny 16 rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunny_16_rule), but this camera has a built-in battery-powered light sensor. Maybe he used it when batteries were dead? Still, I don't know how he would use it, could some numbers represent hours on a sunny day?

Note says

```
19/65 21/90 22/130
```

[image: photo of camera body containing the note]

Or maybe it was somehow used to calculate aperture in relation to distance when using flash?

The previous owner was an electrical engineer, so there might have been some in-memory calculation required in order to use it.

Does anyone have any ideas about what could it mean? I'd love to know how my father-in-law used it :)

Comment: ГОСТ is GOST in Russian. ГОСТ/ASA "ISO" appears to indicate a relationship between the two.

Comment: I've had some russian at school long time ago, so I was able to write it as its printed. I didn't know whether I should "latinize" it or not.  "(ISO)" was added by me (as I thought it might help somebody), it's not written anywhere on camera body :)

Comment: Probably, he was east german, or bought films in east germany frequently?

Comment: He was Polish - maybe DIN standard films were just more available in Poland at some point in time

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Those look like DIN speeds that match values on the GOST meter dial.

GOST was the Soviet film speed standard; it was on the same scale as ASA speed, but 90% the value (so GOST 360 was equivalent to ASA 400).

DIN works like dB, in that each change by 3 doubles or halves the value; that means DIN 24 is ASA 200, 21 is ASA 100, and so forth -- so those figures give 22 as 130, 21 as 90 -- which are the GOST speeds that correspond to FP4+ and Plus-X, while 19/65 is about what you'd have for one generation Kodacolor.

Comment: ГОСТ is GOST in Russian, BTW.

Comment: That must be it! GOST/ASA values arent exactly as in online tables but they match numbers on camera body gauge

Comment: @zworek, I can confirm that 65-90-130 were the most common stock of (older) Soviet film. 65 (later 64) was probably the most popular.

Comment: Also, I suspect that the "-X" after "30" indicates that 1/30th is the flash synchronization speed, assuming it has a focal plane shutter.

Comment: @JanSteinman Correct -- like most SLRs, the Zenit 12XP has a focal plane shutter; horizontal traveling, as I recall, and like most horizontal focal plane shutters, sync speed is 1/30.  I didn't say anything about that because it has nothing to do with the label strip the questioner was asking about.

Answer (score 10):

It's just a little conversion reference for film speeds – equating German DIN standard with Soviet GOST (ГОСТ) standard.

See [Table 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_speed#Conversion_between_current_scales) in the Wikipedia article on 'Film Speed' for example film stocks.